# returning emptystring if columnn name not exists

Tags: sql

I have a very simple select statement like

```
SELECT Column-Name
FROM Object
WHERE ID = 123
```

where the `Column-Name` is dynamically generated. Is there a possibility to get an empty string if column not exists?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Simple. If the column name doesn't exist, the server will generate an error telling that the column does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge hack for SQL Server

SQL is batch based: when submitted to the database engine, the whole batch is parse and a plan compiled. If a column or object does not exist, you'll get an error.

You can test the metadata to see if it exists (`COLUMNPROPERTY`) then use `EXEC` to have the `SELECT` in an separate batch

```
IF COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('Object'), 'Column-Name', 'ColumnID') IS NOT NULL
   EXEC ('SELECT Column-Name FROM Object WHERE ID = 123')
ELSE
   SELECT '' AS Column-Name;
```

Personally, I'd never expect this to be in production code or running on my database servers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a `desc object` or something similar and validate if the column name exists before firing the query? 
Otherwise you will end up doing funny things to work around the sql error

Comment: what does it means by 'desc object'

Comment: `desc table;` The SQL command to get the columns within a table with their properties. You can first query that and verify that the column exists and then later execute your select or not based on that knowledge